# React - wrapped component does not render

Tags: reactjs, antd

Could someone tell me the difference between the two examples below, the top one renders correctly but the bottom one doesn't render the "XYZ" content at all? Can you also tell me why they behave differently and how I can "wrap" a component like this?

```
import React from 'react';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import {  Collapse  } from "antd";


const { Panel } = Collapse;


export default function ScraperList({ scraper }) {
    console.log(scraper);
  return (
  <Collapse accordion>
    <Panel header={scraper.name} key={scraper.id}>
      <p>XYZ</p>
    </Panel>

  </Collapse>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import {  Collapse  } from "antd";


const { Panel } = Collapse;


function Scraper({ scraper: { id, name } }) {
  return (
    <Panel header={name} key={id}>
      <p>XYZ</p>
    </Panel>
  );
}

export default function ScraperList({ scraper }) {
    console.log(scraper);
  return (
  <Collapse accordion>
    <Scraper scraper={scraper}/>

  </Collapse>
  );
}
```

I would have thought they would work the same because the markup would be the same?

Comment: you have an issue to destructor object you can  ({ id,name}) with the item   scrapers={id,name}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Collapse` is using the React [Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) to manipulate it's direct children and give it extra props. In this case, Collapse expects that child to be `Panel` and hence gives it extra props that it needs to complete the operation. This is done with `cloneChild` API.

```
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],  // this is the extra props that can be passed into component.
  [...children] // this is for sending modified/new children
)
```

When you add an extra component like `Scraper` into the mix, `Panel` does not receive the said props and cannot render. But you can forward the props to `Panel` through `Scraper`:

```
import {  Collapse  } from "antd";


const { Panel } = Collapse;


function Scraper(props) {
  return (
    <Panel {...props} header={props.scraper.name} key={props.scraper.id}>
      <p>XYZ</p>
    </Panel>
  );
}

export default function ScraperList({ scraper }) {
  return (
    <Collapse accordion>
      <Scraper scraper={scraper} />
    </Collapse>
  );
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tkebx2?file=index.js)

While this could most certainly work, it is not the recommended way to go about it, as we might still be missing some direct relationship that they have accounted for. To see how this works with `rc-collapse` that AntD uses underneath:

[Source](https://github.com/react-component/collapse/blob/22ad1270b5b1e24a675a38819bc7e041fa817cfc/src/Collapse.jsx#L102)